# How can I back out of caching in ActiveModelSerializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, active-model-serializers

Today I was attempting to set up caching using ActiveModelSerializers.  I was having a lot of problems (my connection kept timing out).  So I attempted to revert all my changes, including deleting the branch I was working on.

However, ever since I tried to set up caching, the model I was working with has exhibited strange behavior.  It looks like it's still loading the cache elements.  This is causing a huge performance hit when trying to access the endpoint for that model.

```
Started GET "/api/v1/entities" for ::1 at 2016-11-17 16:50:44 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Api::V1::EntitiesController#index as JSON
  Entity Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities"  ORDER BY "entities"."name" ASC
  Group Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" IN (2, 3, 1)  ORDER BY "groups"."name" ASC
  Platform Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "platforms".* FROM "platforms" WHERE "platforms"."id" IN (3, 8)  ORDER BY "platforms"."name" ASC
  HardwareType Load (19.3ms)  SELECT "hardware_types".* FROM "hardware_types" WHERE "hardware_types"."id" IN (1, 3, 19, 8)
  EntityType Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "entity_types".* FROM "entity_types" WHERE "entity_types"."id" IN (1)
  EntityOperationalState Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "entity_operational_states".* FROM "entity_operational_states" WHERE "entity_operational_states"."entity_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
  OperationalState Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "operational_states".* FROM "operational_states" WHERE "operational_states"."id" IN (1)  ORDER BY "operational_states"."name" ASC
  EntityLifecycleState Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "entity_lifecycle_states".* FROM "entity_lifecycle_states" WHERE "entity_lifecycle_states"."entity_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
  LifecycleState Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "lifecycle_states".* FROM "lifecycle_states" WHERE "lifecycle_states"."id" IN (2)  ORDER BY "lifecycle_states"."name" ASC
  IpAddress Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ip_addresses".* FROM "ip_addresses" WHERE "ip_addresses"."entity_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
  IpType Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "ip_types".* FROM "ip_types" WHERE "ip_types"."id" IN (1)
  IpUse Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "ip_uses".* FROM "ip_uses" WHERE "ip_uses"."id" IN (1, 2)
[active_model_serializers]   Entity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "entities"."name" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "entities"."name" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   Entity Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "entities"."name" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "entities"."name" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[active_model_serializers]   Entity Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "entities"."name" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "entities"."name" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Json (71.13ms)
Completed 200 OK in 617ms (Views: 474.3ms | ActiveRecord: 27.8ms)
```

The `[active_model_serializers]` Load and CACHE are the new things that lead me to believe the serializer still attempting to load from cache.

My other models, which I didn't touch load with just one `[active_model_serializers]` statement, which is the behavior I expected.

```
Started GET "/api/v1/groups" for ::1 at 2016-11-17 16:56:15 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::GroupsController#index as JSON
  Group Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups"  ORDER BY "groups"."name" ASC
  Platform Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "platforms".* FROM "platforms" WHERE "platforms"."id" IN (8, 3)  ORDER BY "platforms"."name" ASC
  GroupOperationalState Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "group_operational_states".* FROM "group_operational_states" WHERE "group_operational_states"."group_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
  OperationalState Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "operational_states".* FROM "operational_states" WHERE "operational_states"."id" IN (1)  ORDER BY "operational_states"."name" ASC
  GroupLifecycleState Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "group_lifecycle_states".* FROM "group_lifecycle_states" WHERE "group_lifecycle_states"."group_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
  LifecycleState Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "lifecycle_states".* FROM "lifecycle_states" WHERE "lifecycle_states"."id" IN (2)  ORDER BY "lifecycle_states"."name" ASC
  GroupConfigurationProfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "group_configuration_profiles".* FROM "group_configuration_profiles" WHERE "group_configuration_profiles"."group_id" IN (1, 2, 3)
  ConfigurationProfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "configuration_profiles".* FROM "configuration_profiles" WHERE "configuration_profiles"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)  ORDER BY "configuration_profiles"."name" ASC
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Json (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 51ms (Views: 36.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)

Started GET "/api/v1/ip_addresses" for ::1 at 2016-11-17 16:58:34 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::IpAddressesController#index as JSON
  IpAddress Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "ip_addresses".* FROM "ip_addresses"
  Entity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE "entities"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)  ORDER BY "entities"."name" ASC
  IpUse Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "ip_uses".* FROM "ip_uses" WHERE "ip_uses"."id" IN (1, 2)
  IpType Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "ip_types".* FROM "ip_types" WHERE "ip_types"."id" IN (1)
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Json (2.85ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 14.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Those extra trips to the db are slowing down my load times, as you can see.  These models all have around 3 objects right now, but when I was testing with many more records, this becomes a huge problem.

How can I force ActiveModelSerializer to either ignore the cached items?

A better option would be to figure out where those fragments were cached, so I can clear them out.  I tried Rails.cache.clear, but this has no effect.  I also tried, rebooting the computer, and also shutting down my Redis instance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  Apparently this has nothing to do with the caching work I was doing.

I had a circular reference to the entity name in my has_many relationship